# Create google calendar events server-side in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-calendar-api

I have an event flutter app where I would like to send users a Google Calendar invite. I am having issues figuring out the best strategy. I used this code https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events to test the creation of events on the backend (in Google Cloud Function).

I am not sure about how to authenticate.
If I use a a service account I cannot invite the user since I get

```
"Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."
```

and to enable "Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority" I need Google Workspace

Maybe I could use a logged user identity in order to do this but I am not sure how to authenticate in this case.

What is the easiest way?
Service account seems easier but how can I overcome the problem of user invitation?

Comment: Can you elaborate about this calendar invite? Do you want it to come from the user or from your app? You could use OAuth to get authorization from the user to grant your app access to send invitations on their behalf, but I don't know if this fits your use case.

Comment: It’s an event. Either the user create an event on its own calendar or the app sends the invite. Both could work